# Maxed out connections of Mysql5.7

Tags: mysql

I have a 5.7 mysql server, where in I keep getting "ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url:

I tried "SHOW PROCESSLIST" and killing the processes. But soon Mysql server is reaching max connections.

Is there any way I can maintain a higher connection.

Does mysql 8 has simmilar issue.

Comment: Try to give mysql more RAM.

Comment: Do you really that many parallel queries? Maybe you should be optimizing the application instead of MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql 8 can maintain more connections. here [Mysql error 1040](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331032/mysql-error-1040-too-many-connection) Martin answers your question.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Could you please edit your answer to include the most relevant parts of Martin's answer? Or perhaps the whole answer since it's quite short anyway.